# deployment jax-ws on weblogic fails

Tags: web-services, weblogic, jax-ws, weblogic11g

my beaweblogic did not startup successfully.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks

```
failed to preload on startup in Web application: "/app".
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlException: Unable to find namespace for prefix 'tns'. This is used in element [part: null]
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.framework.jaxrpc.server.ServerEnvironmentFactory.getWsdlDef(ServerEnvironmentFactory.java:227)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.framework.jaxrpc.EnvironmentFactory.getService(EnvironmentFactory.java:429)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.framework.jaxrpc.EnvironmentFactory.buildDeploymentContext(EnvironmentFactory.java:621)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.framework.jaxrpc.EnvironmentFactory.getDeploymentContext(EnvironmentFactory.java:606)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.framework.jaxrpc.TubelineDeploymentListener.createServer(TubelineDeploymentListener.java:74)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlException: Unable to find namespace for prefix 'tns'. This is used in element [part: null]
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlReader.createQName(WsdlReader.java:196)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlPart.parse(WsdlPart.java:117)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlMessage.parsePart(WsdlMessage.java:136)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlMessage.parseChild(WsdlMessage.java:126)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlExtensible.parse(WsdlExtensible.java:98)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

---

for me there is no helpful information in it.

thanks.

```
failed to preload on startup in Web application: "/app".
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlException: Unable to find namespace for prefix 'tns'. This is used in element [part: null]
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.framework.jaxrpc.server.ServerEnvironmentFactory.getWsdlDef(ServerEnvironmentFactory.java:227)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.framework.jaxrpc.EnvironmentFactory.getService(EnvironmentFactory.java:429)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.framework.jaxrpc.EnvironmentFactory.buildDeploymentContext(EnvironmentFactory.java:621)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.framework.jaxrpc.EnvironmentFactory.getDeploymentContext(EnvironmentFactory.java:606)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.framework.jaxrpc.TubelineDeploymentListener.createServer(TubelineDeploymentListener.java:74)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSTubelineAssemblerFactory$TubelineAssemblerImpl.createServer(WLSTubelineAssemblerFactory.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl.(WSEndpointImpl.java:158)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSContainer$WLSEndpointFactory$WLSEndpointImpl.(WLSContainer.java:419)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSContainer$WLSEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(WLSContainer.java:404)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:230)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:476)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:519)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSDeployedServlet.getEndpoint(JAXWSDeployedServlet.java:187)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.registerEndpoint(JAXWSServlet.java:269)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.init(JAXWSServlet.java:69)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSDeployedServlet.init(JAXWSDeployedServlet.java:58)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:521)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1913)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1887)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1805)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3041)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1374)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:452)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:204)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:60)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:117)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:204)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:60)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:629)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:206)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:53)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:184)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:361)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:51)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:196)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:30)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:233)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:169)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:123)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:173)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:89)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
Caused by: weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlException: Unable to find namespace for prefix 'tns'. This is used in element [part: null]
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlReader.createQName(WsdlReader.java:196)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlPart.parse(WsdlPart.java:117)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlMessage.parsePart(WsdlMessage.java:136)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlMessage.parseChild(WsdlMessage.java:126)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlExtensible.parse(WsdlExtensible.java:98)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlDefinitions.parseChild(WsdlDefinitions.java:558)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlExtensible.parse(WsdlExtensible.java:98)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlDefinitions.parse(WsdlDefinitions.java:483)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlDefinitions.parse(WsdlDefinitions.java:416)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlImport.parse(WsdlImport.java:121)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlDefinitions.parseChild(WsdlDefinitions.java:552)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlExtensible.parse(WsdlExtensible.java:98)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlDefinitions.parse(WsdlDefinitions.java:483)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlDefinitions.parse(WsdlDefinitions.java:416)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlDefinitions.parse(WsdlDefinitions.java:402)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlFactory.parse(WsdlFactory.java:79)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.framework.jaxrpc.server.ServerEnvironmentFactory.getWsdlDef(ServerEnvironmentFactory.java:216)
    ... 57 more

    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1376)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:452)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:204)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:60)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:117)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:204)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:60)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:629)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:206)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:53)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:184)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:361)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:51)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:196)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:30)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:233)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:169)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:123)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:173)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:89)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlException: Unable to find namespace for prefix 'tns'. This is used in element [part: null]
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlReader.createQName(WsdlReader.java:196)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlPart.parse(WsdlPart.java:117)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlMessage.parsePart(WsdlMessage.java:136)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlMessage.parseChild(WsdlMessage.java:126)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlExtensible.parse(WsdlExtensible.java:98)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlDefinitions.parseChild(WsdlDefinitions.java:558)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlExtensible.parse(WsdlExtensible.java:98)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlDefinitions.parse(WsdlDefinitions.java:483)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlDefinitions.parse(WsdlDefinitions.java:416)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlImport.parse(WsdlImport.java:121)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlDefinitions.parseChild(WsdlDefinitions.java:552)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlExtensible.parse(WsdlExtensible.java:98)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlDefinitions.parse(WsdlDefinitions.java:483)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlDefinitions.parse(WsdlDefinitions.java:416)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlDefinitions.parse(WsdlDefinitions.java:402)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlFactory.parse(WsdlFactory.java:79)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.framework.jaxrpc.server.ServerEnvironmentFactory.getWsdlDef(ServerEnvironmentFactory.java:216)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.framework.jaxrpc.EnvironmentFactory.getService(EnvironmentFactory.java:429)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.framework.jaxrpc.EnvironmentFactory.buildDeploymentContext(EnvironmentFactory.java:621)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.framework.jaxrpc.EnvironmentFactory.getDeploymentContext(EnvironmentFactory.java:606)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.framework.jaxrpc.TubelineDeploymentListener.createServer(TubelineDeploymentListener.java:74)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSTubelineAssemblerFactory$TubelineAssemblerImpl.createServer(WLSTubelineAssemblerFactory.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl.(WSEndpointImpl.java:158)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSContainer$WLSEndpointFactory$WLSEndpointImpl.(WLSContainer.java:419)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSContainer$WLSEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(WLSContainer.java:404)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:230)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:476)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:519)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSDeployedServlet.getEndpoint(JAXWSDeployedServlet.java:187)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.registerEndpoint(JAXWSServlet.java:269)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.init(JAXWSServlet.java:69)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSDeployedServlet.init(JAXWSDeployedServlet.java:58)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:521)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1913)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1887)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1805)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3041)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1374)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:452)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:204)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:60)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:117)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:204)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:60)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:629)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:206)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:53)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:184)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:361)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:51)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:196)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:30)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:233)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:169)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:123)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:173)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:89)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not really providing enough details (e.g. do you bundle jax-ws or any other jar in the war that could conflict with WebLogic's one?) to provide a precise answer but maybe have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846213/jaxws-2-1-5-on-weblogic-10-3-1-instead-of-pre-installed-jaxws-2-1-1/1855759#1855759) where I describe how to use a custom version of jax-ws instead of the version bundled with WebLogic.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Adding weblogic-application.xml to my META-INF directory solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the last line of the stack trace above, you'll see "Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace." The log files under your Weblogic installation directory will give you more detailed information, and may point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be that the XSD's or WSDL's that you are using have something like  but the namespace 'tns' is not declared in that WSDL/XSD, or an XSD is being imported wrong.