# Web Sphere Web Services Run-time Implementation

Tags: web-services, websphere

According to the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846213/jaxws-2-1-5-on-weblogic-10-3-1-instead-of-pre-installed-jaxws-2-1-1) question, WebLogic uses the JAX-WS RI internally to implement the JAX-WS standard. Does anyone know if Web Sphere uses any third party package as its web services run-time implementation (JAX-WS, JAX-RPC or any other not standard option that may be available on WAS)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSphere's JAX-WS implementation is built on AXIS2. See [this Redbook](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247618.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should not worry about the engine used by the WAS run-time. What you need to be aware of is the specs that you are after supported by WAS.

Look at this URL for the Supported Specs for WAS 7

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rovr_specs.html

Look at 
Table 7. Supported specifications and APIs for Web services. The product supports the specifications and APIs in this table.

Also refer to the FAQ on WebServices @ 
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rwbs_faq.html

HTH

Manglu

Comment: Thanks, but the implementation is exactly what I care about, not the specs :)

Comment: Hi Hila, Apologies as i did not get the intent of your question. Have a look at this URL: (where it talks about WAS and APache Open Source stack in the WS space) http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.iseries.doc/info/iseries/ae/rwbs_faq.html?resultof=%22%41%70%61%63%68%65%22%20%22%61%70%61%63%68%22%20%22%41%78%69%73%22%20%22%61%78%69%22%20