# Override JAX-WS version used by Weblogic 10 - Dynamic WSDL with inline schemas

Tags: jax-ws, weblogic-10.x, java-metro-framework

Has anyone successfully updated the JAX-WS version used by Weblogic 10.3.3?

I've been trying to do what's described in the accepted answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846213/jaxws-2-1-5-on-weblogic-10-3-1-instead-of-pre-installed-jaxws-2-1-1) for hours with no luck.

I'm using Maven to resolve my dependencies and I've tried with combinations of the following libraries in my WAR module (Web service project):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.jws</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsit-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsit-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1-1</version>
    </dependency>
```

That is basically to ship a newer version of JAX-WS with my application.

In my EAR module I've played with the `weblogic-application.xml` file overriding different packages:

```
    <package-name>javax.jws.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.xml.ws.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.xml.bind.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.xml.soap.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.sun.xml.*</package-name>
```

That is to indicate Weblogic to use my classes instead of the classes it has in itself.

Currently my Weblogic 10.3.3 is using JAX-WS 2.1.5 and when I deploy a web service it dynamically generates a wsdl file, the generated wsdl is importing xsds (schemas) and I would like to tell Weblogic to generate the wsdl with inline schemas, that's why I'm trying to override the used JAX-WS version hoping a more recent version uses inline schemas.

Another option would be to generate the wsdl with inline schemas during development and somehow tell Weblogic to use that one instead of generating a dynamic version, do anyone know how to do that? is it putting it in a specific path on the WAR? what about the wsdlLocation attribute on the @WebService annotation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: definitely include the error message you hit.

Comment: If I deploy without any of the changes I described, the app deploys successfully and I can see the generated (dynamic) wsdl with the legend: _Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Oracle JAX-WS 2.1.5._, but when I deploy with the changes  the app is still successfully deployed BUT the wsdl is simply not generated. "This Web Service is not currently available"

Comment: I see. Thanks for that explination. You are going to want to crank up the debugging on the JAX-WS to DEBUG. Because JaxWS 2.1.5 is open source... you can turn on a debugger and watch where it gets in the WSDL generation process before it fails. Start with getting some debug logs and look for error messages related to autogenerating the WSDLs.

Comment: That is a good idea, I'll look into that right now and post my findings, thanks @NicholasDiPiazza

Comment: Once you figure out how to get the DEBUG logs for JAX-WS when this problem occurs... attach that info here as a pastebin and I'll take a looksie.

Comment: @NicholasDiPiazza, in Weblogic I go to 'Home > Summary of Servers > AdminServer > Debug' and enable debug settings for all scopes and attributes, then I deploy the app and my server log file is gigantic but there's nothing about wsdl generation in it :S Besides that I added a root appender that should log everything to the log4j config file used by the domain where my app is deployed and I can't find anything there either. Any suggestion?

Comment: Hmmm not sure. It's going to be a Log4j appender with the jax-b namespace

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to get JaxWs 2.2.6 running in Weblogic 10.3.5
I know your are working on 10.3.3 but this solution should also work.

I followed the steps from this METRO discussion:
http://www.java.net/node/695058#comment-772902

Not all steps from there are really required. So here is the description what I have done.

**Steps for war file**

1) Package your webservice as war file

2) in the war file you need a sun-jaxws.xml file under WEB-INF directory (for detailed information look here: `http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxws/jaxws-war.html`)

3) place the wsdl and xsd file under WEB-INF/wsdl

4) register `WSServlet` and `WSServletContextListener` in your `web.xml`
(for some help look here http://java.dzone.com/articles/jax-ws-deployment-five-minute)

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>MyWebService</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>MyWebService</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/MyWebService</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

5) Place at least one service file under `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/services`

i used `javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider`
and as content in the file (impl class of the provider): `com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl`
you can get this file from jaxws-rt.jar
place also other service files here (for example for different XeceresParserFactory)

**reason**: Weblogic generates at runtime a file called: `_wl_cls_gen.jar` . And here it looks for service files in the first place. When weblogic founds a service file there all other files are loaded from from jar files as espected. *at least it behaves like this*

6) Create a `weblogic.xml`
set `<prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>` to false

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd      http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.2/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
  <context-root>/LogisticsWebservice</context-root>
  <container-descriptor>
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>        
  </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Structure of war file:

```
WEB-INF
|-> classes
    |-> META-INF
        |-> services
            |-> javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider
|-> lib
    |-> alle projektspezifischen jars außer die Abhängigkeiten für JaxWS
|-> wsdl
    |-> MyWebService.wsdl
    |-> MyObjects.xsd
|-> sun-jaxws.xml
|-> web.xml
|-> weblogic.xml
```

**Steps for ear file**

1) Pack your war file in an ear file

2) Place a JaxWs Service Finder class under `APP-INF/classes`
you can use the existing class files from JaxWs-rt.jar

3) Place jaxws-rt, all dependencies and xerces-2.9.1 and xalan-2.7.1 under `APP-INF/lib`

4) Create an `application.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE application PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD J2EE Application 1.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/application_1_3.dtd">
<application>
  <display-name>MyWebService</display-name>
  <module id="MyWebService">
    <web>
      <web-uri>MyWebService.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/MyWebService</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```

5) Create an `weblogic-application.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-application xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.2/weblogic-application.xsd">

  <application-param>
    <param-name>webapp.encoding.default</param-name>
    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>  
  </application-param>

  <prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>com.ctc.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.sun.xml.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.sun.istack.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.sun.msv.datatype.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.sun.msv.driver.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.sun.msv.grammar.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.sun.msv.reader.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.sun.msv.relaxns.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.sun.msv.scanner.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.sun.msv.util.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.sun.msv.verifier.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.sun.msv.writer.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.sun.wsit.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.jws.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.xml.bind.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.xml.soap.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.xml.stream.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.xml.ws.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.xml.activation.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.xml.annotation.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.xml.mail.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.xml.security.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.xml.registry.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.xml.rpc.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.xml.crypto.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.apache.xerces.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javanet.staxutils.*</package-name>
    <package-name>jp.gr.xml.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.codehaus.stax2.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.glassfish.gmbal.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.iso_relax.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.jcp.xml.dsig.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.jvnet.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.relaxng.*</package-name>

  </prefer-application-packages>

  <prefer-application-resources>
    <resource-name>META-INF/services/*</resource-name>
  </prefer-application-resources>
</weblogic-application>
```

**Attention**: jars which are in ear file under `APP-INF/lib` should not be in war file under `WEB-INF/lib`

Structure of ear file:

```
|-> APP-INF
    |-> classes
        |-> com
            |-> sun
                |-> xml
                    |-> ws
                        |-> util
                            |-> ServiceFinder.class
                            |-> ServiceFinder$1.class
                            |-> ServiceFinder$ComponentExWrapper.class
                            |-> ServiceFinder$CompositeIterator.class
                            |-> ServiceFinder$LazyIterator.class
    |-> lib
        |-> activation-1.1.jar
        |-> gmbal-api-only-3.1.0-b001.jar
        |-> ha-api-3.1.8.jar
        |-> istack-commons-runtime-2.4.jar
        |-> javax.annotation-3.1.1.jar
        |-> jaxb-api-2.2.4.jar
        |-> jaxb-impl-2.2.5.jar
        |-> jaxws-api-2.2.8.jar
        |-> jaxws-rt-2.2.6.jar
        |-> jsr181-api-1.0-MR1.jar
        |-> management-api-3.0.0-b012.jar
        |-> mimepull-1.8.jar
        |-> policy-2.3.1.jar
        |-> relaxngDatatype-20020414.jar
        |-> resolver-20050927.jar
        |-> saaj-api-1.3.4.jar
        |-> saaj-impl-1.3.18.jar
        |-> serializer-2.7.1.jar
        |-> stax-api-1.0-2.jar
        |-> stax-ex-1.7.jar
        |-> stax2-api-3.1.1.jar
        |-> streambuffer-1.4.jar
        |-> txw2-20110809.jar
        |-> woodstox-core-asl-4.1.2.jar
        |-> xalan-2.7.1.jar
        |-> xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar
        |-> xml-apis-1.3.04.jar
|-> META-INF
    |-> application.xml
    |-> weblogic-application.xml
|-> MyWebService.war
```

Now deploy your ear file to weblogic.

when you open your wsdl file `http://localhost:7001/MyWebService/MyWebService?wsdl` you should see this comment:

```
<!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.6b21  svn-revision#12959. -->
```

hope this how-to is/was somehow usefull.

for some debug informations I added this to my ServiceImpl class:

```
private static String getImplementationInfo(String componentName, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class componentClass)
{
  CodeSource source = componentClass.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
  return MessageFormat.format(
      "{0} implementation: {1} loaded from: {2}",
      componentName,
      componentClass.getName(),
      source == null ? "Java Runtime" : source.getLocation());
}


public MyWebServiceResponse sayHello(MyWebServiceRequest request) throws MyWebServiceFault
  if (LOG.isDebugEnabled())
  {
    com.sun.xml.ws.util.Version jaxwsVersion = com.sun.xml.ws.util.Version.RUNTIME_VERSION;
    LOG.debug("JaxWS major=" + jaxwsVersion.MAJOR_VERSION + "; buildVersion=" + jaxwsVersion.BUILD_VERSION + "; buildId="
        + jaxwsVersion.BUILD_ID + "; svnRev" + jaxwsVersion.SVN_REVISION);
    LOG.debug(getImplementationInfo("JaxWS", com.sun.xml.ws.util.Version.class));
    LOG.debug(getImplementationInfo("JaxB", com.sun.xml.bind.Util.class));
    LOG.debug(getImplementationInfo("DocumentBuilderFactory", DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().getClass()));
    LOG.debug(getImplementationInfo("XPathFactory", XPathFactory.newInstance().getClass()));
    LOG.debug(getImplementationInfo("TransformerFactory", TransformerFactory.newInstance().getClass()));
    LOG.debug(getImplementationInfo("SAXParserFactory", SAXParserFactory.newInstance().getClass()));
  }

  // do something

  return myWebServiceResponse;
}
```

regards
Alex

PS: As a new user i#m only allowed to post 2 hyperlinks, please excuse this...

Answer (score 2):

I used this solution and was able to get this working...
But the problem is that I need to send proper client certificate so I created a custom SSLSocketFactory that I assigned to the binding:
bp.getRequestContext().put(JAXWSProperties.SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY,
                fact.getSSLSocketFactory());

Problem is that weblogic doesn't use it. It uses its own HTTPsConnection with standard factory. I tried to implement a weblogic SSLSocketFactory but the put into the binding complains rightfully that it is not the sun class.

After a lot of time wasted I created a template of the call (by running my code as standalone), then I use XML to replace/update nodes (+ action in http header). It works nicely and I got rid of all those changes that where required.
I know it is a bit radical, but honestly to implement a call it works very well.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to achive the same (use JAXWS 2.1.5 in weblogic 12c) for my webservices, but eachtime it picks the JAXWS library from weblogic server (not from my application lib)  any suggestion welcome