# Failed to parse WSDL javax.wsdl.WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Cannot create a secure XMLInputFactory

Tags: web-services

while deploying one war file which is web service call im getting the exception like

```
Failed to parse WSDL
javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create a secure XMLInputFactory.
```

I have gone through many forums and couldn't find the absolute solution.Iam struggling with this exception from last three days and couldn't find solution.Please help me out.

Please see the exception in detail

```
Aug 23, 2013 12:08:21 PM org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean isEmptywsdl
WARNING: **Failed to parse WSDL
javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR:** java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create a secure XMLInputFactory
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:256)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:205)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.isEmptywsdl(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:2603)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.isFromWsdl(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:541)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:545)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:205)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:159)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:454)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:334)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.startup(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:238)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.serverStarted(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:148)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.listeners.WSDiscoveryServerListener.startServer(WSDiscoveryServerListener.java:73)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.ServerLifeCycleManagerImpl.startServer(ServerLifeCycleManagerImpl.java:61)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:360)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.startup(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:238)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.serverStarted(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:148)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.listeners.WSDiscoveryServerListener.startServer(WSDiscoveryServerListener.java:73)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.ServerLifeCycleManagerImpl.startServer(ServerLifeCycleManagerImpl.java:61)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:360)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.startup(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:238)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.serverStarted(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:148)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.listeners.WSDiscoveryServerListener.startServer(WSDiscoveryServerListener.java:73)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.ServerLifeCycleManagerImpl.startServer(ServerLifeCycleManagerImpl.java:61)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:360)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.startup(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:238)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.serverStarted(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:148)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.listeners.WSDiscoveryServerListener.startServer(WSDiscoveryServerListener.java:73)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.ServerLifeCycleManagerImpl.startServer(ServerLifeCycleManagerImpl.java:61)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:360)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.startup(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:238)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.serverStarted(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:148)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.listeners.WSDiscoveryServerListener.startServer(WSDiscoveryServerListener.java:73)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.ServerLifeCycleManagerImpl.startServer(ServerLifeCycleManagerImpl.java:61)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:360)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.startup(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:238)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.serverStarted(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:148)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.listeners.WSDiscoveryServerListener.startServer(WSDiscoveryServerListener.java:73)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.ServerLifeCycleManagerImpl.startServer(ServerLifeCycleManagerImpl.java:61)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:360)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.startup(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:238)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.serverStarted(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:148)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.listeners.WSDiscoveryServerListener.startServer(WSDiscoveryServerListener.java:73)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.ServerLifeCycleManagerImpl.startServer(ServerLifeCycleManagerImpl.java:61)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:360)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.startup(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:238)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.serverStarted(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:148)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.listeners.WSDiscoveryServerListener.startServer(WSDiscoveryServerListener.java:73)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.ServerLifeCycleManagerImpl.startServer(ServerLifeCycleManagerImpl.java:61)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:360)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.startup(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:238)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.serverStarted(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:148)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.listeners.WSDiscoveryServerListener.startServer(WSDiscoveryServerListener.java:73)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.ServerLifeCycleManagerImpl.startServer(ServerLifeCycleManagerImpl.java:61)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:360)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.startup(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:238)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.serverStarted(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:148)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.listeners.WSDiscoveryServerListener.startServer(WSDiscoveryServerListener.java:73)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.ServerLifeCycleManagerImpl.startServer(ServerLifeCycleManagerImpl.java:61)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:360)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.startup(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:238)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.serverStarted(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:148)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.listeners.WSDiscoveryServerListener.startServer(WSDiscoveryServerListener.java:73)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.ServerLifeCycleManagerImpl.startServer(ServerLifeCycleManagerImpl.java:61)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
**Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create a secure XMLInputFactory**
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.createXMLInputFactory(StaxUtils.java:300)
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.getXMLInputFactory(StaxUtils.java:255)
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.createXMLStreamReader(StaxUtils.java:1416)
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.createXMLStreamReader(StaxUtils.java:1318)
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:246)
```

Answer (score 10):

You are using a version of CXF that require a "Secure XMLInputFactory". WoodStox 4.2.0 provided such a XMLInputFactory.

It looks like WoodStox 4.2.0 is already a dependency of CXF, so you must have another XMLInputFactory implementation that is picked up by the classloader before the WoodStox one.

I had the same problem and for me it was a GlassFish implementation that caused the conflict.

If you use Maven, check carefully your dependencies.

At last you may debug into CXF. Put a breakpoint in **org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.createXMLInputFactory**, then restart your server, you will see what jar contains the implementation that is used. Try remove this jar from WEB-INF/lib and see what's happen.

see also [CXF 2.7.x Woodstox Compatibility via Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903216/cxf-2-7-x-woodstox-compatibility-via-maven)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your Webservices impl class.
Because if we are developing contract first web service then our CXF tool will generate all Binding class, Service Interface and it's implementation class.

So if you check once your generated impl class it will be like below :

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;

/**
 * This class was generated by Apache CXF 2.6.9
 * 2014-02-07T11:41:26.598+05:30
 * Generated source version: 2.6.9
 * 
 */

    @javax.jws.WebService(
                          serviceName = "TrainInfoServices",
                          portName = "TrainInfoSOAPPort",
                          targetNamespace = "http://www.irctc.org/TrainInfo/types",

                          wsdlLocation = "file:WebContent/WEB-INF/TrainInfo.wsdl",

                          endpointInterface = "org.irctc.traininfo.types.TrainInfo")

    public class TrainInfoImpl implements TrainInfo {
```

But the wsdlLocation variable value  Should be like below: 
     wsdlLocation = "/WEB-INF/TrainInfo.wsdl",

once try with this change and deploy the it will slove..

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Could this bug report be related?

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/WSAS-1297

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into the same situation after upgrading an old project to Java 11, together with switching to Apache CXF 4.0.0.

The root cause of this issue in my case was missing dependency on class **org.codehaus.stax2.XMLInputFactory2**.

The solution to resolve this issue was to include library **stax2-api-4.2.1.jar** into project's classpath.