# JaxWsDynamicClientfactory + java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create a secure XMLInputFactory

Tags: java, maven, cxf, jax-ws, weblogic-10.x

My CXF JaxWs Endpoint is hosted on a weblogic through a war. I'm trying to access an operation from a Stand-alone JaxWsDynamicClient. The Client is getting created but the following exception is thrown while trying o access the operation.

I've pasted the Server Side and Client Side Exception, SEI, client code and the respective Service and Client pom(s). Didn't find any luck researching over this issue, mostly there seems to be no answer.

## Server Exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create a secure XMLInputFactory
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.createXMLInputFactory(StaxUtils.java:314) ~[cxf-core-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.getXMLInputFactory(StaxUtils.java:264) ~[cxf-core-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.createXMLStreamReader(StaxUtils.java:1443) ~[cxf-core-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxInInterceptor.handleMessage(StaxInInterceptor.java:123) ~[cxf-core-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307) ~[cxf-core-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-core-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:243) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:223) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:197) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:149) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:286) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:206) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) [javax.servlet_1.0.0.0_2-5.jar:2.5]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:262) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227) [weblogic.jar:10.3.6.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125) [weblogic.jar:10.3.6.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301) [weblogic.jar:10.3.6.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:184) [weblogic.jar:10.3.6.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3732) [weblogic.jar:10.3.6.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696) [weblogic.jar:10.3.6.0]
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321) [com.bea.core.weblogic.security.identity_1.2.0.0.jar:1.2.0.0]
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120) [com.bea.core.weblogic.security.wls_1.0.0.0_6-2-0-0.jar:6.2.0.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273) [weblogic.jar:10.3.6.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179) [weblogic.jar:10.3.6.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490) [weblogic.jar:10.3.6.0]
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager_1.11.0.0.jar:1.11.0.0]
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221) [com.bea.core.weblogic.workmanager_1.11.0.0.jar:1.11.0.0]
```

## Client exception

```
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Cannot create a secure XMLInputFactory
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.unmarshalFault(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:798)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1636)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1525)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1330)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:638)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:423)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:326)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:279)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invokeWrapped(ClientImpl.java:314)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invokeWrapped(ClientImpl.java:305)
    at com.learn.ws.client.LibraryServiceClient.main(LibraryServiceClient.java:40)
```

## SEI

```
@WebService(name="library", targetNamespace="http://service.ws.learn.com")  
@BindingType(value="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/")

public interface LibraryService {

        @WebMethod(operationName="getBooks")
        @ResponseWrapper(className="com.learn.ws.model.BookList", targetNamespace="http://service.ws.learn.com")
        @WebResult(name="bookList")
        public BookList getBooks();
}
```

## Service pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.learn.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>LibraryWeb</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

    </properties>

    <build>
    <finalName>LibraryWeb</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Other Web dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- C X F -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies> 
</project>
```

## Client Code

```
        JaxWsDynamicClientFactory dcf = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance();
        Client client = dcf.createClient("http://localhost:7001/LibraryWeb/services/library?wsdl");

        Object[] res;
        try {
            res = client.invokeWrapped("getBooks");
            System.out.println("List Of Books \n"+res[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

## Client pom

```
<project 
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
  <artifactId>LibraryWebClientSpring</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> 
</project>
```

Comment: Check the link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903216/cxf-2-7-x-woodstox-compatibility-via-maven

Answer (score 0):

You need an javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory service provider. The woodstox-core-asl package provides this (package com.ctc.wstx). This is the default implementation for Wildfly and packaged with Apache CXF.
I don't use Maven, but this should work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
    <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem with CXF 3.0, and fixed in this way:

[CXF web service client: "Cannot create a secure XMLInputFactory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114945/cxf-web-service-client-cannot-create-a-secure-xmlinputfactory)

```
<prefer-application-packages>
       <package-name>com.ctc.wstx.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```